# Python Module Imports - Explicit vs Implicit Relative Imports

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Last night, when working on my mac, I set up some module imports in my `__init__.py`'s

```
from MongoProvider import MongoProvider
from Settings import Settings
```

etc. I'm unsure of what version of Python is on that machine. I'll edit the question later with that info once I have it.

Today, working on a different machine, which is Windows and using Python 3.3.3, my module imports were breaking. By adding an explicit relative import (adding a leading dot), I was able to fix the issue.

```
from .MongoProvider import MongoProvider
from .Settings import Settings
```

The trace I'm receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 5, in <module> from modules.route_handlers import Route_Handlers
File "C:\Users\willb\bearded-dubstep\modules\route_handlers\Route_Handlers.py", line 9, in <module> from modules.backend_providers import Settings
File "C:\Users\willb\bearded-dubstep\modules\backend_providers\__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from MongoProvider import MongoProvider
ImportError: No module named 'MongoProvider'
```

My Project Layout is

root 
|_modules 
  |_api_helpers 
    |  __init__.py 
    |  InvalidUsage.py 
    |  response_utils.py 
  |_backend_providers 
    |  __init__.py 
    |  MongoProvider.py 
    |  Settings.py
  |_route_handlers 
    |  __init__.py 
    |  Route_Handlers 
|  app.py

Any ideas what would cause this? Is there a configuration file I should be looking at?

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: Windows is using 3.3.3. I'm not sure what's on my Mac. Whatever is shipping stock these days.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Like the exception in Windows? You're project's file layout, etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) imports section:

> Implicit relative imports should never be used and have been removed in Python 3.

As Python 3.3 is the one causing you trouble, making you explicit import relatives modules, I assume this explains the situation. It's probably that on Mac you have Python 2.x, that's why it works there.

Looking at your project's file distribution, `Settings.py` and `MongoProvider` are indeed relative modules. This means that the removal of *implicit relative imports* in Python 3 is the one causing you trouble, because the import system is unable to find the module:

```
ImportError: No module named 'MongoProvider'
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Python Version on your mac is 2.x while the Python on your windows is 3.x.

I have met the same problem before using module tkinter (which is Tkinter in Python 2.x).

It seems that we need to use from XXX.xxx import xxx to import...●﹏●

I don't know why, maybe it's the designer's adjusting to Python.