# import from a module imported in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package

I previously had had the following structure (as part of a bigger project):

```
lib/
  __init__.py
  somemodule.py
```

Where `__init__.py` was empty and `somemodule.py` included some method `def hello()`. Now all across my code repository there were numerous imports of that method, specifically `from lib.somemodule import hello`.

For various reasons, I now want `somemodule.py` to be moved into a subpackage. Meaning, I want the structure to be:

```
lib/
  sublib/
    __init__.py
    somemodule.py
  __init__.py
```

And figured that if now `lib/__init__.py` would contain:
`from sublib import somemodule`, running `from lib.somemodule import hello` would still work (in essence, making the change of structure "transparent" for now).

However, if some external code runs `from lib.somemodule import hello`, the error `ImportError: No module named somemodule` is raised, whilst running `from lib import somemodule` works.

I'd appreciate an explanation on what I'm doing wrong, along with any suggestion on how to make `from lib.somemodule import hello` run despite the folder structure change.

Comment: are you sure `from lib import somemodule` works? Is it not `from lib.sublib import somemodule`?

Comment: yes. after adding `from sublib import somemodule` into `lib/__init__.py`, `from lib import somemodule` works.

Comment: hey, may I post it as an anwer? :)

Comment: @Pynchia That does not solve my problem. My problem is that `from lib.somemodule import hello` doesn't work.

Comment: ahem.. you mean `from lib.sublib.somemodule import hello`, right?

Comment: @Pynchia No, I meant what I wrote. You should re-read the question. Obviously `from lib.sublib.somemodule import hello` would work, but what I want is for `from lib.somemodule import hello` to work. I figured this could be handled by adding said line in `lib/__init__.py`, but that doesn't work, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `from lib.somemodule import hello` to work, you need to have a module named `somemodule` in your package `lib`. Calling `from sublib import somemodule` will only add your module to the scope of your package, not define a new module, which the import mechanism can find. That's also why `from lib import somemodule` works. It only imports the global variable `somemodule` from the package `lib`.

So having a module `lib/somemodule.py` with contents

```
from .sublib.somemodule import *
```

would be the simplest and cleanest way to resolve that issue, maybe including some kind of [DeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning). Then remove it some time in the future.

#### *Can do*

The following ideas are based on informations found in the documentation for [the import statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

> The first place checked is `sys.modules`, the cache of all modules that have been imported previously.

So a simple *can do* solution is writing the module cache yourself:

```
import sys
from .sublib import somemodule
sys.modules[__package__+'.somemodule'] = somemodule
```

Maybe adding a finder to [`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) might be a little cleaner:

```
import sys
from .sublib import somemodule
class SomemoduleFinder(object):
    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname == __package__+'.somemodule':
            return self
    def load_module(self, fullname):
        return somemodule
sys.meta_path.append(SomemoduleFinder())
```

If you had a setup before, where `lib/__init__.py` didn't import `somemodule` directly, you could also place the import inside of the `SomemoduleFinder.load_module` method to mirror that behaviour. Though this only worked with Python 2 for me.

#### Additionally

Have a look at [Python Module Imports - Explicit vs Implicit Relative Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20706335/3385212) to prevent portability issues in the future when porting to Python 3.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted the answer but am looking for a solution that doesn't involve keeping the file there (there's rarely a "no can do" in python...) And BTW, I read through the question you linked to and didn't see how this was relevant.

Comment: `from sublib import somemodule` is an implicit relative import and should not be used. But it'll only be relevant when targeting Python 3.

Comment: true, but problem still applies when it's replaced with `from lib.sublib import somemodule`. Thanks for the tip, anyways.

Comment: I added some *can do* approaches for you, but I wouldn't consider them to be clean or portable.